# Code is running on ax client but not in batch because of the assert permissions?

Tags: axapta

I have this type of code which I want to run in batch. 
If I run on the client, it is working fine, but in batch, it is not working. The Batch job finished with the Error status, but no logs.

Can you please help me?

sNewLine = #newLine;

```
sqlStr = "Set Language British " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "UPDATE p " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "SET " + amountStr + " = ct.sumLA, " + qtyStr + " = ct.sumQ, ItemStatRecordType = " + int2str(DSDItemStatRecordType::Item) + " " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "FROM ";
sqlStr += SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getloginDatabase();
sqlStr += ".DBO.DSDITEMSALESSTATISTICS  AS p " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "INNER JOIN ( " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "  SELECT " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "a.ItemId, " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "SUM(a.LINEAMOUNTMST) sumLA, " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "SUM(a.QTY) sumQ, " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "cj.InvoiceAccount Customer, " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "a.DATAAREAID    ctDataAreaId, " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "a.PARTITION        ctPartitionId " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "FROM ";
sqlStr += SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getloginDatabase();
sqlStr += ".DBO.CUSTINVOICETRANS as a " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "inner join ";
sqlStr += SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getloginDatabase();
sqlStr += ".DBO.CUSTINVOICEJOUR as cj " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "on cj.INVOICEID = a.INVOICEID " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and cj.INVOICEDATE = a.INVOICEDATE " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and cj.DATAAREAID = a.DATAAREAID " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and cj.PARTITION = a.PARTITION " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "where a.INVOICEDATE ";
sqlStr += strFmt("between '%1' ", date2str(_fromDate, 123, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4) );
//sqlStr += "between '01-01-2011' ";
sqlStr += strFmt("and '%1' ",  date2str(_toDate, 123, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4));
sqlStr +=  sNewLine;
//sqlStr += "and '01-01-2012' ";
sqlStr += "GROUP BY ItemId, cj.INVOICEACCOUNT, cj.DATAAREAID, cj.PARTITION, a.DATAAREAID, a.PARTITION " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += ") as ct " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "ON ct.ItemId = p.ItemId  " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and ct.Customer = p.CustAccount " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and p.DATAAREAID = ct.ctDataAreaId " + sNewLine;
sqlStr += "and p.PARTITION = ct.ctPartitionId " + sNewLine;


connection = new Connection();

perm = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sqlStr);

// Check for permission to use the statement.
perm.assert();
statement = connection.createStatement();
updatedRows = statement.executeUpdate(sqlStr);

CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run in batch, it runs as the AOS user, and in client, it's most likely running as your domain user account (depending on setup).

I would guess the AOS user doesn't have appropriate SQL permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't now if the permition for AOS user is the case. I have admin permission on the user that I use for running the batch job, and also I can run other batch jobs with the same user and they finishes successfully.

Comment: In your batch, write `info(sqlStr)` and look at the SQL command it's trying to run. Perhaps `SysSQLSystemInfo::construct().getloginDatabase();` isn't working correctly in batch or needs permissions asserted.

Comment: Hello,I debugged now more on this issue. O my class I have more methods which use this kind of code connection = new Connection();

perm = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sqlStr);

// Check for permission to use the statement.
perm.assert();
statement = connection.createStatement();
updatedRows = statement.executeUpdate(sqlStr);

CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();    and for this method is working, but for the similar methos is crashing on UpdatedRows line. Practicle is working to give permission first time but when is going on the second method is crashing. On user running is working.

Comment: and I check the code of the methods is exactly the same I tried to change the order of the code and is passing the code only first time

Comment: You need to get permission for each statement, and if you are using nested SQL calls, you can't reuse the same statement/connection because they're currently in use.